# Upgrading Laravel Mix to the latest version causes problems

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, internationalization, laravel-mix

I am working on an app that before upgrading to Laravel 9 was working fine. I used Laravel Shift for the Laravel 9 upgrade and that bumped `laravel-mix` to the latest version `6.x` and the problems started. I had some problems compiling which was weird but I fixed it. Now, I compile but I get the following error when I try to run the frontend:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'silent')

this is the code that causes it:

```
VueI18n.prototype._initVM = function _initVM (data) {
  var silent = Vue.config.silent;
  Vue.config.silent = true;
  this._vm = new Vue({ data: data, __VUE18N__INSTANCE__: true });
  Vue.config.silent = silent;
};
```

I have no idea what this code is for?

I am running `Vue` version `2.5.22` with Laravel 9. Also, `vue-i18n` 8.28.2.

Here is my `app.js`:

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import router from './router';
import App from "./components/App";
import {store} from './store';

import Vuelidate from 'vuelidate';

import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n';

import { messages } from './locales/de';

const i18n = new VueI18n({
  locale: 'de', // default and only locale
  messages,
});

Vue.use(Vuelidate);

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    i18n,
    router,
    store,
    components: {
        App
    },
});
```

Googling reveals nothing. Any ideas?

Comment: Try to include `VueI18n` as a component before creating an instance, so before the `const il8n = new VueI18n({` write `Vue.use(VueI18n);`

Comment: I’ll write my comment as an answer so you can close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to include `VueI18n` as a component first before creating an instance:

```
Vue.use(VueI18n);
const il8n = new VueI18n({});
```